# Null Space Binary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $H\in \mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$. The null-space matrix for $H$ is always in this form $[I|A]$ yes or no why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean you're multiplying $H$ on the left by that proposed matrix.

The answer is "no" in general. Split the matrix $H=\begin{bmatrix}H_1\\H_2\end{bmatrix}$ into two blocks so that it can be block-multiplied with the one you wrote. In order for the product to be zero, the rows of $H_2$ have to be in the span of the rowspace of $H_1$, which will not happen in general. (Just imagine all the rows of $H_1$ being $001$ and all the rows of $H_2$ being $100$: the parity check will not be of that prescribed form.)

However, in the context you added, you can pass to an equivalent code to $H$ by permuting the rows of $H$ so that $H_1$ has full rank. Using column operations, you can find an $R$ such that $HR=\begin{bmatrix}-A\\I \end{bmatrix}$, and then you see that the columns of $HR$ generate the same code, and at the same time $[I|A]\begin{bmatrix}-A\\I \end{bmatrix}=0.$

Comment: I ask this because I am study McEliece Cryptosystem. And to get the generator matrix of Goppa code I am using the right_kernel() SAGE instruction
Krnl = H.right_kernel();

but I get always these form. The parity check matrix is building using the matrix
T, V and D. How I will be able to get generator matrix in other form?



H: is a parity check matrix.
T: Toepliz
V: Vandermonde
D: Diagonal

Comment: Ah, well that context helps! There will always be an equivalent code with a parity check in that form. I need to fix the answer anyway.